# Simple oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

When we are studying harmonic oscillations, we come across with this equation:

$\ddot{x} + c^2x = 0   \tag{1}$

We know immediately that the period of the x oscillations is equal to $T = \frac{2\pi}{c}$

The question is:

I know how to prove the period is that equality AFTER solve the equation, but there is a way to discover it before to solve it (Suppose is the first time you see that, and don't know x is a trigonometric function)?
I imagined to put x(t) = x(t+T), but this change nothing in  equation ($1$).

Comment: It is just $0$, the (1) should denote what equation i am talking about, i used it to clarify. But as apparently it did not help, i erased it

Comment: You can use \tag{1} to number equations.

Answer (score 0):

You actually not need to solve the equation, Once you have given a equation of the form

$$a= \ddot{x}=-\omega_0^2x$$

You can compare to find $\omega_0$ and thus $T=2\pi/\omega_0$.

---

If the potential energy has a minumum at equilibrium,nearly every bound system oscillates like a harmonic oscillator about its equillibrium position if it slightly perturbed.

$$U(r)\approx U(r_0)+ \frac{1}{2}(r-r_0)^2\left(\frac{d^2 U}{dr^2}\right)_{r_0}$$

from where we can deduce
$$k=\left(\frac{d^2 U}{dr^2}\right)_{r_0}$$

Once we have $k$, We can get $T$ simply by applying
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$

---

If the force law is given then
$$F=ma=-kx\Rightarrow a=-\frac{k}{m}x=-\omega_0^2 x$$
from which one can deduce time period.

Although these all true only for simple harmonics oscillator.

---

There is another method using energy conservation. Consider one dimensional motion.
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+U(x)$$

or
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{[E-U(x)]}}+\mathrm{constant} $$

The  points at which the potential energy equals the total energy,
$$U(x)=E$$
give the limits of the motion. There are turning points.

The period of oscillations is given by
$$T(E)=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_{x_1(E)}^{x_2(E)} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{[E-U(x)]}} $$

That's another method to deduce time period without solving equation of motion.

Comment: Your first solution is like a tautology (a simple harmonic oscillator has that period since it behaves as a simple harmonic oscillator). Ok for the second approach.